# Python : Split string every three words in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tokenize

I've been searching around for a while now, but I can't seem to find the answer to this small problem.

I have this code that is supposed to split the string after every three words:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = {
    'State':['Arizona AZ asdf hello abc','Georgia GG asdfg hello def','Newyork NY asdfg hello ghi','Indiana IN asdfg hello jkl','Florida FL ASDFG hello mno']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1,columns=['State'])
df1

def splitTextToTriplet(df):
    text = df['State'].str.split()
    n = 3
    grouped_words = [' '.join(str(text[i:i+n]) for i in range(0,len(text),n))]
    return grouped_words

splitTextToTriplet(df1)
```

Currently the output is as such:

```
['0     [Arizona, AZ, asdf, hello, abc]\n1    [Georgia, GG, asdfg, hello, def]\nName: State, dtype: object 2    [Newyork, NY, asdfg, hello, ghi]\n3    [Indiana, IN, asdfg, hello, jkl]\nName: State, dtype: object 4    [Florida, FL, ASDFG, hello, mno]\nName: State, dtype: object']
```

But I am actually expecting this output in 5 rows, one column on dataframe:

```
['Arizona AZ asdf', 'hello abc']
['Georgia GG asdfg', 'hello def']
['Newyork NY asdfg', 'hello ghi']
['Indiana IN asdfg', 'hello jkl']
['Florida FL ASDFG', 'hello mno']
```

how can I change the regex so it produces the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

For efficiency, you can use a regex and `str.extractall` + `groupby`/`agg`:

```
(df1['State']
 .str.extractall(r'((?:\w+\b\s*){1,3})')[0]
 .groupby(level=0).agg(list)
)
```

output:

```
0     [Arizona AZ asdf , hello abc]
1    [Georgia GG asdfg , hello def]
2    [Newyork NY asdfg , hello ghi]
3    [Indiana IN asdfg , hello jkl]
4    [Florida FL ASDFG , hello mno]
```

regex:

```
(             # start capturing
(?:\w+\b\s*)  # words
{1,3}         # the maximum, up to three
)             # end capturing
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
def splitTextToTriplet(row):
    text = row['State'].split()
    n = 3
    grouped_words = [' '.join(text[i:i+n]) for i in range(0,len(text),n)]
    return grouped_words

df1.apply(lambda row: splitTextToTriplet(row), axis=1)
```

which gives as output the following Dataframe:

|  | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | ['Arizona AZ asdf', 'hello abc'] |
| 1 | ['Georgia GG asdfg', 'hello def'] |
| 2 | ['Newyork NY asdfg', 'hello ghi'] |
| 3 | ['Indiana IN asdfg', 'hello jkl'] |
| 4 | ['Florida FL ASDFG', 'hello mno'] |